# How to load generated .bin from processor(AM5728 i'm using) to internal flash of STM32 Board

Tags: stm32, texas-instruments, stm32-hal

I am using an stm32h series controller and i wanted to load generated .bin file into the controller's internal flash form processor(AM5728) end.if anybody has any idea then please let me know.

Comment: You need to enable some method to do it. The STM32 has a hard baked uart bootloader, or you can add your own.

Comment: You can also implement SWD programming - it quite essy and straigtforward, First you need to load flash loading code to the ram and then you can upload and flash the actual data.

Comment: The documentation for the STM32 part describes the various ways you have to get into the part, swd, uart, spi, i2c, usb (dfu) are possible candidates, but to some extent it depends on the specific chip/family.  All the ones I know support swd and a version of their uart bootloader.  Where you build the binary doesnt matter, the file format should conform to one that the tool you use supports.  Talking to the uart bootloader is the easiest of the choices,  for a few bucks on ebay and free software you can get in through swd.